# How to fix TypeScript error Property 'isBoom' does not exist on type 'Boom<any> | ResponseObject'

Tags: node.js, typescript, hapi.js

The following source code returns TypeScript errors:

```
this.hapi.ext({
  type: 'onPreResponse',
  method: async (request, handler) => {
    if (request.response.isBoom && request.response.message !== 'Invalid request payload input') {
      if (request.response.isServer) {
        logger.captureException(request.response, null, {
          digest: this.requestDigest(request)
        });
      } else {
        logger.captureMessage(request.response.message, 'info', null, {
          digest: this.requestDigest(request)
        });
      }
    }
    return handler.continue;
  }
});
```

[image]

> Property 'isBoom' does not exist on type 'Boom | ResponseObject'.
>   Property 'isBoom' does not exist on type 'ResponseObject'.
>
> Property 'isServer' does not exist on type 'Boom |
>   ResponseObject'.   Property 'isServer' does not exist on type
>   'ResponseObject'.
>
> Argument of type 'string | ((httpMessage: string) => ResponseObject)'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type '(httpMessage:
>   string) => ResponseObject' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How can I fix them? Is there a problem with `@types/hapi`?

Comment: try `isBoom in request.response` instead of  `request.response.isBoom`

Comment: You will need type guards: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Doesn't work. TypeScript error: The left-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', 'string', 'number', or 'symbol'.

Comment: Sorry I meant `'isBoom' in request.response`

Comment: @ritaj Your suggestion looks promising! Will report back here to confirm.

Comment: @sunknudsen I installed the module and the checks work for me, added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `response` is a union `ResponseObject | Boom | null` we can only access common members of a union unless we use a type-guard.

There are several types of type-guards and you ca read more about the [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) .Below I use an `in` type guard to discriminated based on the existence of the property

```
import { Server } from 'hapi';

const hapi = new Server({})

hapi.ext({
    type: 'onPreResponse',
    method: async (request, handler) => {
        if (request.response && 'isBoom' in request.response && request.response.message !== 'Invalid request payload input') {
            if (request.response.isServer) {
                request.response.message // string 
            }
            return handler.continue;
        }
    }
});
```

Since the type `Boom` is a class an `instanceof` typeguard should also work:

```
hapi.ext({
    type: 'onPreResponse',
    method: async (request, handler) => {
        if (request.response && request.response instanceof Boom && request.response.message !== 'Invalid request payload input') {
            if (request.response.isServer) {
                request.response.message // string 
            }
            return handler.continue;
        }
    }
});
```

**Note** in both cases I added a check for `request.response` to exclude `null` from the union. This is only required by the compiler if `strictNullChecks` are enabled, but might be a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to break it down.